# Communication between Java and C++ process

Tags: java, c++, ipc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inter-process communication between languages/operating systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773097/inter-process-communication-between-languages-operating-systems)

I need to do inter-process communication between java and C++ process, since both are different process so I can't use JNI. I'm thinking to use socket communication, but do any other solution exists apart from socket communication? Which is better and faster?

Comment: What about standard input and output? Other possibilities: named pipes, shared memory and an IPC system like DBus. But I like your mentioned solution about sockets, too; their portability to become a remote connection some time being the most important advantage.

Comment: Sockets are perhaps the simplest depending on what you are trying to do. Start with the simplest you can think of and optimise it if you have measured a performance issue.

Comment: i dn't hv gud hand in java, can be use pipe or shared memory or message queue between C++ and java process. thanxs for any input.

Comment: I've done with C++ and Java using UDP

Comment: @Aniket How did you make UDP reliable?

Comment: I didn't have to because it was on the same machine - UDP on the same machine is _very_ reliable

Comment: @user1808932 A socket is bi-directional pipe over loopback.

Comment: Since you are asking if there are other solutions I have to mention CORBA...

Comment: @Aniket *Very*, but not 100%. ;)

Comment: @ aniket: i still feel unsecure about out of order packet problem in case of UDP. @leemes:Named pipe won't work with java

Comment: @user1808932 you can get the order packets by appending a payload with it that keeps the number

Comment: @user1808932 Found using google: [Named pipes Java <-> .NET](http://v01ver-howto.blogspot.de/2010/04/howto-use-named-pipes-to-communicate.html) Although it uses .NET to create a named pipe, I don't think that it will be any harder in C++. Also: You don't like any of the answers? Or why didn't you upvote any of them?

Answer (score 7):

In general, you have the following possibilities (there might be even more, but these are the "popular" ones):

- **Standard input and output channels.** (+) easy to implement (+) fast (+) easy to debug (-) you can't attach / detach to / from an already running processes
- **Named pipes.** (+) fast (-) system-dependent
- **IPC system, for example DBus.** (-) system-dependent
- **TCP socket communication.** (-) slower, but should be fast enough (+) can easily be extended to a remote communication (+) easy to debug (-) possible TCP port conflict between applications or instances of the same application.

Personally, I'd prefer TCP socket communication because of the possibility to make a remote connection with (almost) no source code changes. However, care has to be taken not to use the same port on the same machine twice, which is impossible. The second instance would fail to listen on the port, as you might already know. A possible workaround is to use port ranges.

Comment: @doc I don't know enough about that. Do you want to add it in my answer / put your own answer?

Comment: If both processes are on the same machine, he can also use shared memory.  Almost certainly the fastest, but it would probably require some JNI on the Java side, and is decidedly system dependent.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm not sure if JVM provides easy access to shared memory for Java processes.

Comment: @doc JVM doesn't.  That's why you'll need the JNI---to get at the shared memory in C or C++.  You'll still have to copy the Java data into or out of the shared memory, but an in-process copy will still be a lot faster than any of the other methods.

Comment: @james : can u elaborate it a bit more, i like to implement share memory one between java and C++ process.

Comment: @user1808932 You'll have to do the actual accesses to shared memory in C or C++, and communicate with the Java via JNI.  Other than that, how you access shared memory is very system dependent: the functions are `mmap` and `munmap`; under Windows, you'll need `CreateFileMapping`, `MapViewOfFile` and `UnmapViewOfFile`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org) or, which looks more appealing to me, [Crossroads I/O](http://www.crossroads.io)?

Answer (score 0):

There are many IPC methods available out there, choosing which one really depends on what you want to do

1. Files: probably the easiest one to implement, only you have to care for syncronization, dirty reads, etc..
2. Signals: I can only so little about it, but it is supposedly fast communication method, I believe it is more complicated to implement
3. Network: my favorite method, each new process/node opens a new port upon spwan, a better alternative is to use a similar mechanism to [ros nodelets](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nodelet) which fires many "nodelets" inside one process. this is a fast method, but not real time

other than that you have semaphores and shared memory and pipes etc..
but none of these is easy to understand and implement, although I believe there should be some libraries for that, also on the OS level